# What does "ribbiting" mean in the sentence "I heard this class is "ribbiting""?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

I'm subtitling the `barely lethal` movie and in one scene which happens in a *biology class*, the new girl sits next to a boy and says:

> I heard this class is "ribbiting."

and the boys answers:

> Well, I wouldn't "leap" to conclusions.
>
> Mr. Drumm can be pretty rough. (Mr. Drumm is the teacher)

Look! I know that `ribbiting` means `The sound made by a frog or toad.`

But I wonder what does that mean in that sentence? It's more like an idiom!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A typical activity in a biology class is to dissect a frog.  So the speakers are making frog jokes.

The girl's line is a pun on the word *riveting* (fascinating, attention-grabbing - something that holds your attention as if it were fastened with [rivets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rivet)) and *ribbit* (an [onomatopoeic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) word for the croaking sound made by a frog).

The quote marks serve to indicate that the speaker is placing extra emphasis on the word *ribbiting*, to call attention to her joke.

The boy is using the set phrase *leap to conclusions* (to make a decision about something based on insufficient evidence, also commonly worded *jump to conclusions*), but emphasizing the word *leap*, because leaping is something that frogs do.  Here the joke involves the double meaning between the figurative and literal senses of *leap*.

The phrase *Kermit suicide* mentioned in comments is another pun: on *commit suicide* (to kill oneself) and [Kermit the Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_the_Frog), a well-known fictional character.